# Use custom version of the Scala standard library

Tags: scala, customization, sbt

In my project, I need to use a custom version of the Scala standard library. I would like to host this version and declare it in my sbt build so that all developers need not worry about the details of fetching and building the project with this custom standard library.

I tried using the settings

```
autoScalaLibrary := false
```

I then added my own scala standard library as an explicit dependency. Unfortunately, sbt was unable to build the project complaining that the standard library was missing. I tried using my own organization name, I tried using the "org.scala-lang" organization name. I tried setting the version to 2.10.3, I tried setting to another name, in occurence, 2.10.3.1. But none of these attempts succeeded in accomplishing what was desired.

I also tried using

```
managedScalaInstance := false
```

but was unable to find documentation on how to easily create a ScalaInstance to fit my needs. All versions of the apply method on the ScalaInstance companion object seemed way to low level for the relatively simple thing I am trying to accomplish.

Thx for any help you may provide.

Comment: By *custom* you mean you've forked scala, made your own changes, build library down to the artifact, defined it as a dependency to ordinary dependency list?

Comment: You might get more help (or at least sympathy!) if this looked like it was a good idea.  For instance, you might tell why a simple additional library won't do the trick.

Comment: we are working on https://codebrew.io/ and we need various fix from the future 2.10.4 for our engine (??? non fatal, synthetic flag in the reflection compiler, etc)

Comment: @EdStaub Let me add to that list a fix in 2.10.4 that allows the reflection ToolBox to produce Range Positions

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yes, that sounds pretty much like what we are doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- we used `ant publish.local` (not 100% sure)
- uploaded to bintray https://bintray.com/jedesah/maven/scala-library/2.10.4-20131126-231426-da7395016c
- then we only add the following resolver + scalaVersion in our build

`scalaVersion := "2.10.4-20131126-231426-da7395016c"`

`resolvers += bintray.Opts.resolver.repo("jedesah", "maven")`

Answer (score -1):

While I don't know for sure, I very much doubt it is possible to swap out just the standard library.

I suspect you will probably need to swap in an entire custom Scala, including your custom standard library, as documented at http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Local-Scala.html

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing right now on my local machine to develop. However, since we are a team, I need a better approach than to require every developer to acquire and build our custom version of the library. It would be much better if we could host these custom versions somewhere so that this whole process appears transparent to the members of our team who should not be concerned with this.

Comment: I see. Sounds like a good feature request, that the custom Scala be obtainable from a `URL`, not just a `File`.

Comment: Publish the custom Scala version to a Maven repository.  No need to make it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @MarkHarrah if I understood correctly: 1) Build scala version 2.10.4-JR 2) publish on bintray/maven 3) set autoScalaLibrary := false 4) add 2.10.4-JR in libraryDependencies

Comment: Not sure why the autoScalaLibrary part is necessary or manually declaring the dependency.  Why not just set the scalaVersion?